# Is there any responsa from the early 1900's discussing how it was proven that the Yerushalmi Kodshim was fake?

Tags: talmud-yerushalmi, kodshim

Quick background ([link](https://tockify.com/bernardrevel/detail/23/1494977400000)):

> In 1907–1909, Shlomo Yehuda Algazi-Friedländer, a mysterious 
>   man from the town of Szatmár in Transylvania, published what 
>   he claimed to be the long-lost tractates of Seder Kodashim 
>   of the Jerusalem Talmud. Though initially welcomed in rabbinic 
>   circles, the work was soon revealed to be a forgery composed 
>   by Friedländer based on his talmudic learning.

I've heard (**EDIT**: attributed to the [**Rogachover Gaon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogatchover_Gaon)) said that one way it was found to be a fake was that every Masechta contains the name of at least one Amora who doesn't appear in any other Masechta-- for Yerushalmi Kodshim this wasn't the case.

**Are there any *teshuvos*/ responsa from that time period (early 1900's) that discuss, dissect, analyze, etc how the Yerushalmi Kodshim was proven to be a fake?**

Comment: https://seforimblog.com/2007/06/story-of-publisher-of-forged-yerushalmi/

Comment: Someone indeed wrote a book about this.

Comment: Not exactly “teshuvos/responsa”, but see Dr. Shprecher’s important intro. to his ed. of R. [Meir Plotzky](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_Dan_Plotzky)’s [Sha’alu Shelom Yerushalayim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/21612); see also [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3153&st=&pgnum=352) for a contemporaneous account by the prolific R. [Yekusiel Yehudah Greenwald](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Greenwald).

Comment: @Oliver thanks!

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Regarding “Nothing new here, keep moving” - that’s what the Rogatchover wrote in a letter to R. Plotsky, saying that the Yerushalmi is a collection of various Talmudic and medieval paraphrases.

Comment: http://www.yerushalmionline.org/articles/yerushalmi_on_kodshim.pdf

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel thank you so much for sharing!